# Redirect in UserControl

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, redirect, spcontext, sputility

I have an issue to redirect page on the page load of my user control
For this i use

```
string sRedirectionURL = "/mylist/forms/allitems.aspx";
SPUtility.Redirect(sRedirectionURL + Request.Url.Query,      
SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEncodeUrl, Context);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't redirect and i have no exception.
Just the message: This page can't be displayed

I tested this without success

```
Response.Redirect(sRedirectionURL, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear to me could you please try below?

Use `Page.Response.Redirect()` inside `UserControls`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work too